# Is it possible to create a Google+ circle of people who liked/shared a public post?

Tags: google-plus

If I'd want to reach a group of the same interest, wouldn't it be the best way to find the people who publicaly liked/plussed this topic?

Is it currently possible to add all people, who liked a post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the API can give you the list of people who +1, share, or comment on a post... currently there is no API that can do circle management. You should be able to write a webapp that provides links to each user in a short format, and then manually add each person to a circle, but that is probably the best you can do at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet. The only possible solution could be using the API, but Google+ API doesn't yet allow WRITE requests. Once(and if) it's available, you could do it easily.